# Getting a residency in italy

Tags: netherlands, residency, italy

I have a Dutch residency card for 5 years. I am married to an Italian. We used to live in the Netherlands. Now we want to move to Italy. What do I meed to do to get a new residency card?

Comment: You will apply in Italy after you move there. You have 90 days.

Comment: Have you lived in the Netherlands for five years or more?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.